# $a ? $b : echo $c not work but $a ? $b : print $c works in PHP

Tags: php, printing, echo

```
//In PHP,
$a ? $b : echo $c  //does not work but 
$a ? $b : print $c //works
```

Is there a reason for this?

BTW,is `not` a keyword in PHP?

Comment: Oh, yes. The ever famous "Doesn't Work" exception.

Answer (score 2):

`echo` **is not a function, it's language construct.** It does not return anything. Another `void` functions always "return" `NULL`. It's why the compiler throws error `unexpected T_ECHO`.

`printf`, however, is a function and always returns `1`.

For example this will work:

```
function echo2($e)
{
    echo($e);
}

$a ? $b : echo2('foo');
```

Comment: Actually, print is a language construct too, but it behaves like a function.

Comment: @stereofrog: so official documentation of PHP (first result in the search) is not an authoritative source on information about whether PHP contains such a thing as "language constructs"?

Answer (score 1):

`echo` does not have a return value, `print` does!

```
 void echo  ( string $arg1  [, string $...  ] )

 int print  ( string $arg  )
```

from [php.net](http://php.net)

This matters in this case since the ternary operator expects *expressions*

```
(expr1) ? (expr2) : (expr3)
```

`echo "something"` cannot be classified as an expression.

`not` is not a [PHP keyword](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php).

Answer (score 0):

there is no `not` keyword in PHP

Answer (score 0):

Is it because echo is a language construct and print is a function?

Answer (score -1):

return value.
if you wrote

```
  $x = $a?$b:echo $c;
```

what value would $x get on $a being false?

print always returns 1.
echo doesn't return anything.

Comment: But I don't have the `$x =` part .Also I tried a function that doesn't have a return value,still works.

Comment: PHP functions that do not explicitly return a value will be 'void', that is, they return 'null'. echo, not being a function but a language construct, doesn't return even that. As for lack of $x = ..., PHP is an interpreter. It first calculates the value of the ?: expression, and only then decides whether to discard it or pass it.

Comment: Could whoever modded my answer down explain what is wrong about it?